# SocketChannel fires isReadable() but nothing to read

Tags: java, android, sockets, nio, socketchannel

I have got a new problem with my Android app. The `SocketChannel` tells me that it `isReadable()` but there is nothing to read.

```
while(running)
    {
        int readyChannels = 0;
        try {
            readyChannels = selector.select();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(readyChannels == 0) continue;

        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

        while(keyIterator.hasNext())
        {
            SelectionKey key1 = keyIterator.next();

            if(key1.isReadable())
            {
                publishProgress(1);
            }

            else if(key1.isWritable())
            {
                publishProgress(2);
            }

            else if(!key1.isValid())
            {
                Log.e("State", "progress error");
                publishProgress(3);
            }
        }
    }
```

I call the needed functions in `onProgressUpdate`. It is a `WebSocket` app so I need to send and receive a handshake. Sending and receiving the handshake works with this while loop. First the `SelectionKey.isWriteable()` and the handshake is sent then the `SelectionKey.isReadable()` and the handshake is read. But then `SelectionKey.isReadable()` is still true. Now the normal read function (not the `readHandshake`) function is called. But there is nothing to read. Here is the code of my read function:

```
public byte[] read(int nBytes)
{
    Log.e("State", "public byte[] read(int nBytes) start");

    byte[] resultData = new byte[1024];
    ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(resultData);
    int remainingBytes = nBytes;

    while(remainingBytes >= 0)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        try {
            bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "channel read");
        }

        if(bytesRead < 0)
        {
            sockState = WebSocketState.WebSocketErrorOccurred;
        }

        else
        {
            remainingBytes = remainingBytes - bytesRead;
            data.put(buffer.array(), 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    Log.e("State", "public byte[] read(int nBytes) done");

    return resultData;
}
```

Now it gets stuck in an endless while loop. remainingBytes never gets < 0 because there is nothing to read and bytesRead stays 0.

My question is why is isReadable true when there is nothing to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `bytesRead < 0` you should close the channel, or at least deregister `OP_READ`. Otherwise you will keep getting `OP_READ` over and over again to tell you about the EOS.

You shouldn't allocate your `ByteBuffer` once per read. Allocating `ByteBuffer`s is an expensive operation. At least allocate it once per entry to the read method. Better still, allocate one per channel when you accept it. You can keep it as, or via, the key attachment so you don't lose it, and so it disappears when you cancel the key or close the channel.

Comment: sry for being naive, but how can I unregister `OP_READ` ?

Comment: @Mayank With `SelectionKey.interestOps()`.

Answer (score 2):

The SelectionKey which has been read all should be removed from the set returned by Selector.

I think this article would help you understand.

[Why the key should be removed in `selector.selectedKeys().iterator()` in java nio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132057/why-the-key-should-be-removed-in-selector-selectedkeys-iterator-in-java-ni)

Comment: I have the same problem even if I remove the selection key from the selection set.