# Why the key should be removed in `selector.selectedKeys().iterator()` in java nio?

Tags: java, nio

I found some sample code of java nio:

```
 ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();  
 Selector selector = Selector.open();  
 server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));  
 server.configureBlocking(false); 
 server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);  

 while(true) {
     selector.select(); 
     Iterator iter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();  
     while (iter.hasNext()) {  
         SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iter.next();  
         iter.remove();  // Why remove it? 
         process(key);  
     }
 }
```

When he gets the selected keys, he remove the key in the loop. Why we should do this?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answers provided by **EJP** and **user270349**, I think I understand it now, let me explain it in detail.

There are 2 tables in the selector:

1. registration table: when we call `channel.register`, there will be a new item(key) into it. Only if we call `key.cancel()`, it will be removed from this table.
2. ready for selection table: when we call `selector.select()`, the selector will look up the registration table, find the keys which are available, copy the references of them to this selection table. The items of this table won't be cleared by selector(that means, even if we call `selector.select()` again, it won't clear the existing items)

That's why we have to invoke `iter.remove()` when we got the key from selection table. If not, we will get the key again and again by `selector.selectedKeys()` even if it's not ready to use.

Comment: No need to 'imagine'. It does have those two sets: the registered keys returned by keys(), and the selected keys returned by selectedKeys().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the Selector never does that, it only adds to the set, so if you don't do it you will reprocess the event yourself next time the Selector returns.

Answer (score 0):

Because until you do it you can't detect new event repetitions.

Comment: Because unless you do it you will *redetect* the *old* events, as repetitions.

Comment: @EJP I think both are true. You can't tell if an event is new or old so you can't detect new events either.

Comment: 'New event repetitions' is meaningless, not 'true'. It is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: "New (event repetitions)", not "(new event) repetitions"

Comment: It's still meaningless. The assumption is that all events are new, and not removing the key violates that.

Answer (score -1):

Because removing key from selected set, as it's been Handled, it will wait for next selection event.

selected set contains keys of the ready channels.

```
 selector.select(); //This may block for a long time. Upon returning, the elected set contains keys of the ready channels.
```

Get an iterator over the set of selected keys and Perform the Business Information

```
Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator(  );
```

Finally Remove key from selected set; it's been handled

```
 it.remove(  );
```

Keys can be directly removed from this set, but not added. Attempting to add to the selected key set throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Very poorly expressed and two years late.

Comment: EJP - two years late for the OP, but great for anyone else finding this post via Google later (which is the real purpose of StackOverflow, remember? to be the best source of programmer related problems / solutions).

Comment: @JakobJenkov So just very poorly expressed then. The first sentence is almost meaningless, and barely answers the question at all on the most generous interpretation, and the rest of it just repeats the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

avoid publicSelectedKeys
 `private final Set<SelectionKey> publicSelectedKeys;`

Answer (score -3):

if  you dont invoke remove method  you  will  find it  also work  fine。

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public class NioServer {
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public final int port;
    private Selector selector;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    NioServer(final int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    void init() throws Exception {
        // 创建 ServerSocketChannel、ServerSocket
        serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocket = serverChannel.socket();
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        // 设置通道为非阻塞模式
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        // 开启通道选择器，并注册 ServerSocketChannel
        selector = Selector.open();
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    }

    void go() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            int num = selector.select();
            if (num <= 0)
                continue;
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            System.out.println(selector.selectedKeys().size()); //等于线程数量
            while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
                final SelectionKey key = keyIter.next();
                System.out.println("所有的key"+key);
                // 接收一个Socket连接
                // key.isAcceptable（）如果为true，说明channnel支持accept（）,也就是说明是一个ServerSocketChannel
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    System.out.println("可以连接的key:"+key);
                    SocketChannel clientChannel = serverChannel.accept();
                    if (clientChannel != null) {
                        clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                        clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    }
                }
                // 如果isReadable()为true,说明是一个SocketChannel
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    String requestContent = read(key);
                    // 业务处理
                    // responseContent=doSomthing(requestContent);
                    write(key, "ok" /* responseContent */);
                }
//          keyIter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    // 从通道读取数据
    String read(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        buffer.clear();// 这一步必须有
        int len = 0;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        while ((len = socketChannel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            byte[] bs = buffer.array();
            String block = new String(bs, 0, len);
            System.out.println("Server read: " + block);
            str.append(block);

        }
        buffer.clear();
        return str.toString();
    }

    // 写数据到通道

    void write(SelectionKey key, String str) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.put(str.getBytes());
        buffer.flip();// 这一步必须有
        socketChannel.write(buffer);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int port = 10000;
        NioServer server = new NioServer(port);
        server.init();
        /// ========================================================
        // 接下来模拟3个Client并发访问服务器
        int poolsize = 1;
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolsize);
        Collection<Callable> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable>(10);
        final String clientname = "clientThread";
        for (int i = 0; i < poolsize; i++) {
            final int n = i;
            // 若每一个Client都保持使用BIO方式发送数据到Server，并读取数据。
            tasks.add(new Callable() {
                @Override
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
                    final InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                    final OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                    final String clientname_n = clientname + "_" + n;
                    // BIO读取数据线程
                    new Thread(clientname_n + "_read") {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            byte[] bs = new byte[1024];
                            while (true) {
                                try {

                                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                int len = 0;
                                try {
                                    while ((len = input.read(bs)) != -1) {

                                        System.out.println("Clinet thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                                + " read: " + new String(bs, 0, len));
                                    }

                                } catch (IOException e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }.start();
                    // BIO写数据线程
                    new Thread(clientname_n + "_write") {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int a = 0;
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);

                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                String str = Thread.currentThread().getName() + " hello, " + a;
                                try {
                                    out.write(str.getBytes());
                                    a++;

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }.start();

                    return null;

                }

            });

        }
        pool.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<Object>>) tasks);
        server.go();

    }

}
```

just  print it  and  test  it 。you will find  even you  not  remove，use
key.isAcceptable()  can  filter   corrent  result

Comment: No you won't. You will keep getting stale events that have already been processed, so for example on OP_READ you will get zero length reads.