# Java NIO SeletionKey iterator and key handling, am I doing it right?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I'm following [this tutorial](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs161/papers/j-nio-ltr.pdf) on Java NIO. I found what appears to be the correct java file [Here](https://code.google.com/p/astudy/source/browse/trunk/applications/astudy/nio/MultiPortEcho.java?r=141). I've adjusted my code to operate on a single port instead of multiple ports, and to simply output the data to the screen rather than echoing it back to the client.

When I run the code, both my version and the version on the hyper-link above, it appears that the channels aren't handled properly. I came to this conclusion simply from the sound of my laptop's fan, and after placing a few quick `System.out.println()` messages I managed to narrow the issue down a bit. At first I thought the `selector.select()` method wasn't blocking for some reason, the channels appeared to be empty, but the `while(hasContent)` loop kept iterating.

After a bit of searching I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132057/why-the-key-should-be-removed-in-selector-selectedkeys-iterator-in-java-ni) and realised that maybe I wasn't handling keys correctly. I adjusted my code to cancel the SelectionKey in the if statement at the bottom of my `while(iterator.hasNext())` loop, once the data has been read from the channel.

This seems to have done the trick, now I get one message informing that there are no more bytes to read before the channel is closed, and things seem to run more smoothly overall.

Here is my code for what I've done so far, am I correct in my thinking about how this should be implemented? Am I cancelling the key at the correct point?

```
public class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int serverPort;
    private int queueLength;

    public ServerRunnable(int serverPort, int queueLength) {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.queueLength = queueLength;

    }

    private boolean running;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
    private ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Selector selector = Selector.open();

            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort));
            System.out
                    .println("DeviceServerV0.2 - Going to Listen for connections on port: "
                            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            running = true;

            SelectionKey serverAcceptKey = serverSocketChannel.register(
                    selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            int count = 0;
            while (running) {
                int keyCount = selector.select();
                System.out.println("keyCount: " + keyCount);
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
                while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keyIterator.next();

                    if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

                        ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key
                                .channel();
                        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                        sc.configureBlocking(false);

                        // Here we add the new connection to the selector
                        SelectionKey newKey = sc.register(selector,
                                SelectionKey.OP_READ);

                        keyIterator.remove();

                    } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {
                        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                        // Going with this from the tutorial for now.
                        // TODO: Implement proper boolean controls here
                        while (true) {
                            buffer.clear();

                            int read = sc.read(buffer);

                            if (read <= 0) {
                                // System.out.println("Bytes read: " + read);
                                System.out
                                        .println("No more bytes, breaking loop.");

                                break;
                            } else {

                                buffer.flip();
                                String result = new String(buffer.array());
                                System.out
                                        .println("Buffer Contents: " + result);

                            }
                        }
                        keyIterator.remove();
                        key.cancel();

                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm also aware that calling `ByteBuffer.array()` doesn't effect the current position in the byteBuffer, so it would still appear as if the buffer hasn't been read. Should I handle this a certain way or is it enough to call `ByteBuffer.clear()` a the start of the loop?

I'm intending to move on to try build an NIO server that uses a pool of threads to handle requests, but I want to be sure my understanding of NIO is correct so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a channel’s `readyOps()` contain `SelectionKey.OP_READ` it implies that *some* data can be read, not that the channel can be read entirely up to its end. But that’s what you are doing in your `while(true)` loop; you are reading and therefore polling a channel until its end has been reached.

The correct way to handle it is to read *once* and do not attempt to read again, unless the next `select` reports that there is more data to read.

Comment: OK Thanks! I've taken out the `while(true)` loop and moved the  `key.cancel()` call into the `if(read <= 0)` . Should that if statement test be `if(read < 0)` though? because `-1` means end of stream, but `0` doesn't, is that correct?  Running the app likes this seems to work fine, the strings are correct, when they are printed to the console.

Comment: Great! Many thanks for your help, I feel I'm finally getting a grip on this. One final question if you don't mind- When I'm reading data from the channel, I'm going to be keeping an eye out for an "End of Message" marker, at which point I'll need to respond. Is it good practice to respond straight away on receiving that mark, or should I set the bit for write operations and let the selector decide when to handle the write operations.  Keeping in mind that eventually I want this system to use a thread pool for processing. I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question here, sorry if it's silly

Comment: When it is the first time you write into the channel, the buffers should be empty, hence you can simply initiate a write. But it wouldn’t hurt to treat the first time write like all other writes, i.e. wait for the channel to be ready for write, having a single piece of code uniquely handling all write operations.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful, I've a much better understanding of this now.

Comment: It does hurt. It adds overhead. And either you have to register OP_WRITE all the time, which results in CPU smoking most of the time, or you have to register OP_WRITE and wait for the next select iteration until you can write, which adds latency. Either way this is far too much overhead, and it is all unnecessary. The correct technique is to write whenever you need to, and only use OP_WRITE while writes return zero, in association with a catchup write run inside the select loop.